# Local storage not updating React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm btrying to save an array of objects in local storage, each time a user clicks a button, i add the username and email fron input fields
but it keeps updating the local storage instead of appending new object to the array

Below is my code

```
const app = () => {
const [allusers,setAllusers] = useState([JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('users')) || '']);
const [id,setId] = useState(0);
const [newuser,setNewuser] = useState({
    'id':id
    'name':'David',
    'email':'david@gmail.com'
})
const handleChange = () =>{
    setNewuser({...newuser,[e.target.name] : e.target.value});
}
  const add = ()=>{
      setAllusers([newuser])
      localStorage.setItem('users',JSON.stringify(allusers))
      setID(id+1); // increase id by 1
  }
  return(

      <div>
        <form>
        <input type="text" name="user" onChange={handleChange}>
        <input type="text" name="email" onChange={handleChange}>
        <button onclick={()=>save}>Save</button>
        </form>
      </div>
  )
}

export default app;
```

Comment: Pass the `onChange={handleChange}` so the function will execute.

Comment: i don't unserstand

Comment: I don't see any function named `save`. Is it typo? You mean `add` right?

Comment: you are not passing e into your handlechange, also you need to prevent the default behavior of the browswer when the onClick runs otherwise it refreshes your browser.  alot of this code needs revision

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to save `allusers` to the `localStorage` right after `setAllUsers()` but [`setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) is **asynchronous**. The value does not have to be updated on the next line. You can read more about it at [reactjs.org, Why is setState giving me the wrong value?](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#why-is-setstate-giving-me-the-wrong-value).

I would recommend to use [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect).

```
const add=()=> {
    setAllusers([... allusers ,newuser])
}

useEffect(()=>{
   // this is called only if the variable `allusers` changes
   // because I've specified it in second argument of useEffect
   localStorage.setItem('users',JSON.stringify(allusers))
}, [allusers]);
```

Comment: Thanks, This works perfectly, each time the `allusers` changes, we update local storage

Comment: just make sure not to get into an infinite rerender loop.

Comment: But how can i update based on id, Here is what i am doing presently for the update function, it actualy works, but the updated row goes to the base of the stored item in local storage,I will prefer it maintains it's position,  `let updatedUsers = allusers.filter((users)=>{
      return users.id !== newuser.id;
    })
    setAllusers([...updatedUsers,newuser])`

Answer (score 2):

There were a lot of syntactical errors and use of functions like `save` which was never declared and still used.

I rewrote the whole example and made it a bit modular so that you can comprehend it better.

Here is the working example:

**Final Output:**

[image]

**Full Source code:**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./style.css";
const App = () => {
  const [allusers, setAllusers] = useState([]);
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");

  const handleName = e => {
    setName(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleEmail = e => {
    setEmail(e.target.value);
  };
  const save = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let newUsers = {
      id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000),
      name: name,
      email: email
    };
    localStorage.setItem("users", JSON.stringify([...allusers, newUsers]));
    setAllusers(allusers.concat(newUsers));

    console.log("Localstorage:", JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("users")));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Localstorage:", JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("users")));
    if (localStorage.getItem("users")) {
      setAllusers(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("users")));
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        <input type="text" name="user" onChange={handleName} />
        <input type="text" name="email" onChange={handleEmail} />
        <button onClick={save}>Save</button>
        <p>{JSON.stringify(allusers)}</p>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

As You inquired in the comment section, here is how you can implement the Update functionality:

**Final Output:**

[image]

Full source code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./style.css";
const App = () => {
  const [allusers, setAllusers] = useState([]);
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [id, setId] = useState(null);

  const handleName = e => {
    setName(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleEmail = e => {
    setEmail(e.target.value);
  };
  const save = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let newUsers = {
      id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000),
      name: name,
      email: email
    };
    localStorage.setItem("users", JSON.stringify([...allusers, newUsers]));
    setAllusers(allusers.concat(newUsers));
    console.log("Localstorage:", JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("users")));
  };

  const setForUpdate = user => {
    setName(user.name);
    setEmail(user.email);
    setId(user.id);
  };

  const update = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let modifiedData = allusers.map(user => {
      if (user.id === id) {
        return { ...user, name: name, email: email };
      }
      return user;
    });

    setAllusers(modifiedData);
    localStorage.setItem("users", JSON.stringify(modifiedData));
    setId(null);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Localstorage:", JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("users")));
    if (localStorage.getItem("users")) {
      setAllusers(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("users")));
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        <input value={name} type="text" name="user" onChange={handleName} />
        <input value={email} type="text" name="email" onChange={handleEmail} />
        <button disabled={!(id == null)} onClick={save}>
          Save
        </button>
        <button disabled={id == null} onClick={update}>
          Update
        </button>
      </form>
      {allusers &&
        allusers.map(user => (
          <div className="userInfo">
            <p>{user.name}</p>
            <p>{user.email}</p>
            <button onClick={() => setForUpdate(user)}>
              select for update
            </button>
          </div>
        ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

You can find the working example here: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-fgg4sc?file=src/App.js)

Comment: Thanks alot for this, I really do appreciate, I tried marking it as second accepted answer

Comment: No issue, I just hope this one also helps. It's okay if you accepted another answer if it solved your question :) PS: You can always upvote if not accept :P

Comment: How can i update based on id, Here is what i am doing presently for the update function, it actualy works, but the updated row goes to the base of the stored item in local storage,I will prefer it maintains it's position,  `let updatedUsers = allusers.filter((users)=>{
      return users.id !== newuser.id;
    })
    setAllusers([...updatedUsers,newuser])`

Comment: I might have to modify the app again but I am almost about to sleep, so Here is the link to my previous answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65192576/5669120

Comment: check out the updated answer, I have implemented the update functionality.

Comment: Thanks @Ketan Ramteke, I just sent a request on LinkedIn

Comment: Thanks, I just saw it, please accept my request on LinkedIn

Comment: Yeah, that my name

Answer (score 0):

you are adding only one new user while clicking on add button. You need to copy previous data also when setting all users.

Second thing setting state is async and hence your localStorage and allusers may have different value and to avoid this one you need to use useEffect to set the value.

```
  const add = ()=>{
          setAllusers([...allusers ,newuser])
          setID(id+1); // increase id by 1
      }

useEffect(() => {
localStorage.setItem('users',JSON.stringify(allusers))
},[allusers])
```

Comment: I have done this, It appends the `newuser`,but it adds `' '` to the localstorage once the button is clicked the first time

Comment: did you check initial value of allusers, It seems empty one.

Answer (score 0):

`()=>handleChange` is a function that takes no arguments and returns the `handleChange` function. You probably want `() => handleChange()`, which would take no arguments and INVOKE handleChange.